# Como faço para criar uma tela de login e senha em um fragment?

Tags: android

Estou criando um app para apresentação em minha escola, bom como tenho só essa semana para terminar o app preciso representar um rastreio de um determinado ônibus, então para isso pensei em uma tela de login e senha, onde no caso ao invés de colocar um usuário, colocaria o nome da linha e na senha o numero da parada, ao clicar em buscar me levaria ao resultado demostrativo em uma outra Activity, apenas para mostra como iria funcionar.
Eu criei três ferramentas dentro do meu app agora falta só essa para eu terminar, estou usando um TabLayout com três tabs, que no caso são fragmentos.
Então gostaria que alguém me dessa uma luz pois já revirei a net e não encontrei nada relacionado. Desde já Agradeço

Lembrando que ainda sou iniciante em programação android

Aqui esta o código da parte em que quero adicionar o login e senha

Java/Package/Telas/tela1

```
public class tela1 extends Fragment {
    ListView lista;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public static tela1 novaInstancia() {return  new tela1();}
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View tela = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tela1, null);
        return tela;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){return "Localizar";}
```

Java/MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    private TabLayout Guias;
    private ViewPager abreTela;
    int atualPosicao=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Ferramenta);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //Abre páginas da guia
        abreTela = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.Paginas);
        carregaPaginas();
        //Configuração Guia
        Guias = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.Guias);
        Guias.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        Guias.setupWithViewPager(abreTela);
        Guias.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);

    }

    //Preencher páginas
    private void carregaPaginas()
    {
        QuadroAdaptador quadro=new QuadroAdaptador(getSupportFragmentManager());
        quadro.addPage(tela1.novaInstancia());
        quadro.addPage(tela2.novaInstancia());
        quadro.addPage(tela3.novaInstancia());
        abreTela.setAdapter(quadro);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        abreTela.setCurrentItem(atualPosicao=tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    public void tela3 (View view) {

        Intent intencao = new Intent(this, alvorada.class);
        startActivity(intencao);
    }

    public void tela3maracana (View view) {

        Intent intencao = new Intent(this,maracana.class);
        startActivity(intencao);
    }

    public void tela3res_salvacao (View view) {

        Intent intencao = new Intent(this, res_salvacao.class);
        startActivity(intencao);

    }

    public void telahorariosalvorada (View view){
        Intent intencao = new Intent(this, alvorada_horarios.class);
        startActivity(intencao);

    }
    public void telahorariomaracana (View view){
        Intent intencao = new Intent(this, Maracana_Horarios.class);
        startActivity(intencao);
    }

    public void telahorarioResSalvacao (View view){
        Intent intencao = new Intent(this,ResSalvacao_Horarios.class);
        startActivity(intencao);
    }


}
```

Layout/tela1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/onibus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Ônibus"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numerodaparada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/onibus"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/onibus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/onibus"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Numero Da Parada"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buscar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numerodaparada"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Buscar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: [Você revirou a internet e não encontrou nada?](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=login+password+android+example)

Comment: Mas o seu problema é no fragment ou no login?

Comment: Bom o meu problema e como faço para utilizar o login e senha dentro do fragment

Comment: Achei esse tutorial que é da mesma forma que eu quero, mais no caso ai ele não usa fragments, então gostaria de saber se e possível fazer esse mesmo método utilizando fragment? Aqui o link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ys5psUSlBYg